# Find the matrix of linear transformation of given function with respect to bases $P$ and $Q$.

Tags: linear-algebra, linear-transformations, change-of-basis

---

It is given that $f: \mathbb{R}^2 \to \mathbb{R}^3$
$$f(x, y) = (2x-3y,\ x,\ 5x+y)$$

The bases are given by as follow:

- $P = \{(1, -1), (4, 0)\}$
- $Q = \{(1, 1, 0), (1, 0, 1), (0, 1, 1)\}$

**My approach:**

The transformation matrix w.r.t standard (canonical) basis is $A$,
$$A = \begin{bmatrix}
2 & -3\\
1 & 0\\
5 & 1
\end{bmatrix}$$

Change of basis matrix wrt $P$ basis is $C_1$, such that $C_1 \vec {x_P} = \vec x$

$$C_1 = {1 \over 4}\begin{bmatrix}
0 & -4\\
1 & 1
\end{bmatrix}
\text{ and  }
C_1^{-1} = \begin{bmatrix}
1 & 4\\
-1 & 0
\end{bmatrix}
$$

Change of basis matrix wrt $Q$ basis is $C_2$, such that $C_2 \vec {y_Q} = \vec y$

$$C_2 = {1 \over 2}\begin{bmatrix}
1 & 1 & -1\\
1 & -1 & 1\\
-1 & 1 & 1
\end{bmatrix}
\text{ and  }
C_2^{-1} = \begin{bmatrix}
1 & 1 & 0\\
1 & 0 & 1\\
0 & 1 & 1
\end{bmatrix}
$$

Now,
$$\vec y = A \vec x$$
$$C_2 \vec {y_Q} = A C_1 \vec {x_p}$$
$$\vec {y_Q} = C_2^{-1} A C_1 \vec {x_p}$$
$$\vec {y_Q} = D\ \vec{x_p}$$
Now D is given  by
$$D = C_2^{-1}AC_1$$

What is the problem in this method? I am not able to get the correct answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems you're confusing the change of basis matrix and its inverse. The columns of a change of basis matrix $P$ are made up of the coordinates of the vectors in the *new* basis in the old basis, and the relation between the coordinates $X$ of a vector in the old basis, $X'$ its coordinates in the new basis (seen as a single-column matrix) is
$$X=PX'.$$

Therefore, here,  if I denote $P$ the change of basis matrix in $\mathbf R^2$, $Q$  the change of basis matrix in $\mathbf R^3$, we have $Y=AX$, i.e.
$$QY'=APX'\iff Y'=(Q^{-1}AP)X',$$
and therefore $D=Q^{-1}AP$, or, with your notations, $\; D=C_2AC_1^{-1}$.